# MySQL fulltext search over multiple columns: result confusion

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a search query which performs a fulltext search on the DB.

```
$sql = "SELECT
*
FROM 
`tbl_auction_listing` AS `al` 
JOIN 
`tbl_user` AS `u` ON `al`.`user_id` = `u`.`user_id` 
LEFT JOIN
`tbl_gallery_details` AS `gd` ON `al`.`user_id` = `gd`.`user_id`
LEFT JOIN
`tbl_self_represented_details` AS `sr` ON `u`.`user_id` = `sr`.`user_id`
WHERE 
`al`.`status` = '" . ACTIVE . "'
AND
`al`.`start_date` < NOW() 
AND
`al`.`end_date` > NOW()
AND
MATCH(`al`.`listing_title`,
`al`.`description`,
`al`.`provenance`,
`al`.`title`,
`al`.`artist_full_name`,
`al`.`artist_first_name`,
`al`.`artist_last_name`,
`sr`.`artist_name`,
`gd`.`gallery_name`,
`u`.`username`) AGAINST('$search_query' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
```

When I search for 'Cardozo, Horacio' or 'cardozo' or 'horacio' I get no results however I know there is an artist with 2 records in the db with artist_full_name = Cardozo, Horacio.

If I remove all MATCH fields and just have `al`.`artist_full_name` I get 2 results. If I add in `al`.`description` I get 1 result because 'Horacio Cardozo' exists in the description.

Is there a way to have the search return all records if any condition (any search query word) is met in any of the MATCH fields? I tried removing IN BOOLEAN MODE but that produced same results.

Comment: Instead of `IN BOOLEAN MODE`, try `IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE`

Comment: `IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE` is the default mode (ie. when no mode is specified)

Comment: Still produces 0 results when searching. I have checked that all fields in DB are fulltext but still nothing.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It appears that InnoDB tables do not allow searches over several fulltext indexes in the same `MATCH()` condition.

Here your fields do not all belong to the same table, therefore they are covered by different indexes. Notice the same limitation applies if you had a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  f1 VARCHAR(20),
  f2 VARCHAR(20),
  FULLTEXT(f1), FULLTEXT(f2)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

SELECT * FROM t
WHERE MATCH(f1, f2) AGAINST ('something in f2'); -- likely to return no row
```

It *looks like* a fulltext search may only search on the first fulltext index it encounters *but this is only something I deduct [from this experience](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3cc5/5)*, please do not take this for granted.

The bottomline is that you should split your search so as to use one single fulltext index per `MATCH()` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM auction, user, gallery, ...
WHERE
    MATCH(auction.field1, auction.field2) AGAINST ('search query' IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR
    MATCH(auction.field3) AGAINST ('search query' IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR
    MATCH(user.field1, user.field2, user.field3) AGAINST...
```

This is an illustration of a possible query if you had two distinct indexes on `auction` and one one on `user`. You need to adapt it to your actual structure (please post your tables' descriptions if you need more guidance).

Notice this only applies to InnoDB tables. Interestingly, MyISAM tables [do not seem to show the same limitation](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/89dad/9).

---

Update: it turns out this was [a bug in the InnoDB engine](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69762), fixed in 5.6.13/5.7.2. The above example now rightfully fails with "Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list". Indeed, there is no index on `(f1, f2)`, but one on `(f1)` and another one on `(f2)`. [As the changelog advises](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.6/en/news-5-6-13.html):

> Unlike MyISAM, InnoDB does not support boolean full-text searches on
>   nonindexed columns, but this restriction was not enforced, resulting
>   in queries that returned incorrect results.

It is noteworthy that while such queries return a correct result set with MyISAM, they run slower than one might expect, as [they silently ignore existing fulltext indexes](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/89dad/14).

Comment: I can use the * to get anything after that word but is there a way to get words where the search query might begin in the middle of the word? For example: query=pple return results 'apple'

Comment: You could use a search condition such as: `... WHERE field LIKE '%pple'` (`%` is a wildcard) but such query cannot use a fulltext index (nor a regular index either). "[MySQL cannot use an index if the columns do not form a leftmost prefix of the index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-indexes.html)" (this statement is initially intended to describe multi-column indexes, but it is really the same idea for a partial index).

Comment: Your suggestion to use multiple `match ... or match ...` sections in the `where` clause seems to prevent myisam from using the index too.  Independent queries with a `union` works better. E,g, `select * from rsspodcastitems where match title against ("vegetables")  or match subtitle against ("vegetables") --> 16 rows in set (2.46 sec)` whereas `select * from rsspodcastitems where match title against ("vegetables") union select * from rsspodcastitems where match subtitle against ("vegetables") --> 16 rows in set (0.02 sec)`.