# Can't use Fultext search with more than one column

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Table Engine InnoDB

Server version: 5.6.24 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Added Fulltext indexes
[image]

This works:

```
SELECT * FROM resources WHERE MATCH(`short_description`) AGAINST ('Lorem')
```

This works:

```
SELECT * FROM resources WHERE MATCH(`long_description`) AGAINST ('Lorem')
```

This DOES NOT work:

```
SELECT * FROM resources WHERE MATCH(`short_description`,`long_description`) AGAINST ('Lorem')
```

> ## 1191 - Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list

I have also tried creating fulltext index with both columns but get the same error. Have also tried switching engine to MyISAM same error, but also does not return any match row when single columns are used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17459278/mysql-fulltext-search-over-multiple-columns-result-confusion), it appears that InnoDB tables do not allow searching over more than one `FULLTEXT` index column in the same `MATCH` condition.

However, InnoDB *does* support `MATCH` against a single `FULLTEXT` index column, so you can rework your query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM resources
WHERE MATCH(`short_description`) AGAINST ('Lorem')
    OR MATCH(`long_description`) AGAINST ('Lorem')
```

Comment: ok this is helpful, I switched to myisam , created the combined key and now I can run the fulltext query like this: SELECT * FROM resources WHERE MATCH(`short_description`, `long_description`) AGAINST ('Lorem')  - but no rows returned..aargh..I will post  a separate q, if you dont have any clues,,,thanks!